# outline image over entire page width

Tags: graphics, texworks

I am probably not the first to ask this question but I have tried every answer I could find before asking it here.
The problem is that I want an image (eps) be on the top of the page.

I want to add a header on the top of the page starting at an inch from the top and starting at the side of the page (no margin).
I have tried \noindent , raisebox & makebox, outlining it to the left.... All the answers I could find.

However, I keep getting this.
I want it to be higher and starting from the left side of the paper.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\raisebox{100pt}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{figures/eb.eps}}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}



\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
 \AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}}}

blub 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[anchor=north,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at
       ([yshift=-1in]current page.north) 
                       {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.75in]{example-image-a}};

blub
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust `yshift`, `width` and `height` suitable as you need.