# Positioning an Image Anywhere I Want in a Single Page

Tags: graphics

I envision my pdf file to look like this....

[image]

How to achieve that effect in Latex?

Answer (score 5):

You can absolutly place something e.g. with eso-pic (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168683/2388) or with tikz (needs two compilations):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt]at ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
 %only to show the values:
 \draw[red,<->] ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north west) --++ (1,0) node[midway,above]{1cm}; 
 \draw[red,<->] ([xshift=1cm]current page.north west) --++ (0,-1) node[midway,right]{1cm}; 
 \draw[red,<->] ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-3cm]current page.north west) --++ (5,0) node[midway,above]{5cm}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{my_image.png}
\end{document}
```

Please read [this](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-figurehere.html) for about what to do when you want to put a picture at a specific place.

Comment: Admittedly, the question is pretty bad, but where is the placing 'anywhere' here?

Comment: It doesn't look like what I had envisioned....See below...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've edited my answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The output must look like the picture above.....

Comment: @zZ_LateX_HaterZ_zZ: Comparing your non - answer below and your question above, I would suspect some white space around your image file, otherwise I can't explain why your 'answer' image is centered somewhat, while your question image is left aligned